# Mystery filament cleaning fluid

Tags: print-quality, extruder, quality, filament-quality

Whilst looking to fix a different problem I had I came across this video.

It's a filament reel holder, but at 02:40 the person uses a mysterious fluid.  I haven't seen anything like this before (though had wondered).

[Mystery cleaning fluid.](https://youtu.be/X6ArZeWYSZE)

What practical problems would this cleaning fluid mitigate?

Comment: .... and what new problems would it introduce?   Gotta be careful there.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

That's a filament cleaner/oiler combo. The black bottle is a variety of machine oil.

The effect of oilers on prints is heavily disputed in the community. The suggestion of plant oils is a very bad one as they can create residue that stays in the hotend and create clogs.

Comment: For peoples information, that is where the debate starts. Others claim that the residue is actually what coats the hotend and thereby making it more slick, synthetic oil does not create such a coating.

Answer (score 0):

For really long Bowden tubes, some people use Teflon lubricant in a cleaner bead.

Never used it myself, since I use a small tube my printer with the stepper on top of one of the Z axis steel rod mounting plates (Anet A8).

Off topic, but by cooking and being a vaper, I vouch that organic compounds leave gunky residues on hot surfaces/parts.